# IF you miss to see... you MIGHT lose the match(1st conditional?)

Tags: grammar

We often see grammar books with fixed format to be used. When it comes to 1st conditional we see this:

IF+present tense, then WILL...

> - IF you don't study well, you WILL fail the exam.

BUT, can I put it this way:

> - IF you don't study well, you **might** fail the exam.

Can I do this?

Comment: Not germane to your question, but _miss_ takes a gerund, not an infinitive. _If you miss seeing_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

suppose you dropped a ball and it ran down to the basement. And you have to go get it. But the staircase is old and rotten, so you say:

If I step on it, it might collapse.

You used 'if I step on it' from the first conditional, because you are sure you are going to get down.

And for the second part of it, you used the second conditional, because you are not sure if the ladder will hold.

Comment: I get your point. But how do you categorize it now? Is it within 1st conditional format or the second?

Comment: @JohnArvin There's no such thing in Real English as the n-conditionals: those are just teaching tools.

Comment: StoneyB is right, there are people and things they mean, grammar is secondary. And yet... You may need a name for this thing. The problem is, that there are different school and names for this. You may try to call it First conditional, or First conditional with modal verbs, or mixed conditional.